# How to get invoking directory within npm scripts?

Tags: node.js, bash, npm

Let's say my projects `package.json` is located here:

```
project
|- package.json
```

And I execute a npm script here:

```
project
|- package.json
|- some
   |- nested
      |- folder
```

Command:

```
$ cd project/some/nested/folder && npm run myScript
```

`process.cwd()` gives me the wrong directory here inside my npm script. I need the absolute `folder` directory here to use it in my npm script. I'm working on a node module package.

My approach:

```
"myScript": "NODE_PATH=$pwd node ./node_modules/myScript/src/index.js"
```

Gives me `pwd` as `NODE_PATH`.

Comment: Have you tried this : npm run project/some/nested/folder/myScript ?

Comment: It will be a node module later, so it will be inside `node_modules`.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be:

```
process.env.INIT_CWD
```

[Source](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/15277#issuecomment-372111058)